# What is the animated element on this website?

Tags: wordpress

https://www.designingbrandidentity.info
This website loads super fast and the animation too. How is it created?

I am a designer and i want to create the same book animation but after trying .gifs and apngb they are too big.I have the website on WordPress.

Please help me at least understand if i have to give up the concept.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it's a video: https://video.wixstatic.com/video/b352ef_573743f4ee7e445b9f2f5c48ca9bf09a/720p/mp4/file.mp4

Answer (score 0):

The book animation is a video: https://video.wixstatic.com/video/b352ef_573743f4ee7e445b9f2f5c48ca9bf09a/720p/mp4/file.mp4
The video is loaded from another server so it can be loaded faster.